Sheet18.Range("B" & j) = Sheet18.Range("T" & i) Works but Sheet18.Range("C" & j) = Sheet18.Range("O" & i) Errors
I'm getting this error and I don't understand it because I'm just doing a basic task that I have done many times before.  The full code is below, it doesn't error out until it reaches O, I have replaced O with other letters and it work fine then.  Why does column O not work?
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim blankCount As Integer

'find the next blank row
j = 2
Do Until Sheet18.Range("A" & j) = ""
    j = j + 1
Loop

i = 2
blankCount = 0

Do Until blankCount = 4
    If Sheet18.Range("M" & i) = "" Then
        blankCount = blankCount + 1
    Else
        Sheet18.Range("A" & j) = Sheet18.Range("N" & i)
        Sheet18.Range("B" & j) = Sheet18.Range("T" & i)
        Sheet18.Range("C" & j) = Sheet18.Range("O" & i)
        Sheet18.Range("D" & j) = Sheet18.Range("L1")
        j = j + 1
        blankCount = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub


I found how to fix column O.  Excel automatically treats numbers as date format "3 14 12 1:30 PM" and for some reason that format was preventing the macro from working properly.  I selected all cells and changed the format to General and now everything is working as expected.
I guess a follow up question would be, why does Excel format numbers to a date format by default?
